# making a truck and buttons to increase speed, change direction using html/js via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

this is the question for my assignment

> You are required to create the same animation in Canvas. This can be any object: a truck, a car, a cycle an airplane, etc. Many example codes are provided in Blackboard for your help, and I have given you hints in the lecture as well.
>
> 1. The object should be at the left of the screen when you load the page.
> 2. There will be five buttons: start, stop, +, -, and change direction. You can show or hide whichever button you want. It is up to you.
> 3. The object should start moving when click on the start button.
> 4. The object should stop moving when you click on the stop button.
> 5. The object should change the direction when you click on “change direction” button.
> 6. When you click on the + button, the speed of the object should be increased and when you click on the - button, the speed should be decreased.
> 7. Below the buttons, there should be names of the students who did that question.

I've tried to solve it but it's seems not to work with me.

and this is the code for my page.

I want to make change direction button using html/js via jQuery please.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = $("#myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
  var playAnimation = true;
  var startButton = $("#startAnimation");
  var stopButton = $("#stopAnimation");
  var increaseButton = $("#increase");
  var decreaseButton = $("#decrease")
  var x = 0;
  var b = 200;
  var t = 200;
  var w = 200;
  var q = 255;
  var cir = 240;
  var cir2 = 90;
  var ctx;
  startButton.hide();

  startButton.click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    stopButton.show();
    playAnimation = true;
    animate();
  });

  stopButton.click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    startButton.show();
    playAnimation = false;
  });

  /*function increase() {
  speed += 10; 
  };*/


  increaseButton.click(function() {
    var interval = 1000;
    timer = function() {
      interval--;
      //do your thing here

      interval = interval < 40 ? 40 : interval;
      setTimeout(timer, interval);
    };
    timer();
  });

  /*stopButton.click.(function(){
            if(mouseX >= 335 && mouseX <= 390 && mouseY >= 15 && mouseY <= 115){
                x++;//Make faster
            }
            if(mouseX >= 335 && mouseX <= 390 && mouseY >= 295 && mouseY <= 395){
                x--;//Make slower
                if(speed < 0){
                    speed++;//Make faster, I said IT CAN'T GO TO 0 or less...
                }
            }
            
        });*/
  //var increase = x++;
  //var decrease = x--;


  function animate() {
    x++;
    b++;
    t++;
    w++;
    q++;
    cir++;
    cir2++;
    //y++;                          //update
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);  //clear
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
    ctx.fillRect(x, 350, 190, 120);
    ctx.fillRect(b, 410, 60, 60);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(t, 350);
    ctx.lineTo(w, 400);
    ctx.lineTo(q, 400);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#black";
    ctx.fill();

    //var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    //var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cir, 490, 18, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#black';
    ctx.stroke();


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cir2, 490, 18, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#black';
    ctx.stroke();
    //draw();
    // removed for snippet: console.log(x);
    if (playAnimation)
      setTimeout(animate, 20);
    //repeat
  };

  animate();

});
```

```css
/* for snippet - a huge gap at the top makes it unviewable */
#myCanvas { margin-top: -340px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"> 
  <!-- Insert fallback content here --> 
</canvas>
<div>
  <button id="startAnimation">Start</button>
  <button id="stopAnimation">Stop</button>
  <button id="increase"> Increase the speed</button>
  <button id="decrease"> Decrease the speed</button>
</div>
```

Comment: are you whitehat jr. student?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work for you>

Comment: Off topic:  Free lesson 1: keep your code tidy.  Auto-format is your friend.

Comment: Question for you: Which bit makes your lorry move left-right?    Consider that requirements 3-6 are all essentially the same thing once you answer the question of what makes your lorry move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are calling `animate()` inside `animate()`, that is not a good idea.

**Start and stop**

I use this to run the function repeatedly

```
var speed = 10;
var animation = setInterval(function () {
    animate();
}, speed);
```

Now, the `animate()` will run every `speed` ms, which in this case is 10ms. (Canvas will clear and update every 10ms)

To stop the animation, just stop the interval with `clearInterval(animation)`, start again by assigning back it.

```
startButton.click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    stopButton.show();
    animation = setInterval(function () {
        animate();
    }, speed);
});
```

**Change speed**

```
increaseButton.click(function () {
    changeSpeed(-10);
});

decreaseButton.click(function () {
    changeSpeed(10);
});

function changeSpeed(changeValue) {
    speed += changeValue;
    clearInterval(animation)
    animation = setInterval(function () {
        animate();
    }, speed);
}
```

**Change direction**
I have added in new variable named `direction`, which will let the animation move forward when it is in `1` and backward when `-1`.
I replace your code in `animate()`

```
x++;
b++;
t++;
w++;
q++;
cir++;
cir2++;
```

with:

```
x += direction;
b += direction;
t += direction;
w += direction;
q += direction;
cir += direction;
cir2 += direction;
```

and add button that allow it to change the value of `direction`

```
var changeDirection = $("#changeDirection");
changeDirection.click(function () {
    direction *= -1;
})
```

**All together:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var canvas = $("#myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
    var playAnimation = true;
    var startButton = $("#startAnimation");
    var stopButton = $("#stopAnimation");
    var increaseButton = $("#increase");
    var decreaseButton = $("#decrease");
    var changeDirection = $("#changeDirection");
    var x = 0;
    var b = 200;
    var t = 200;
    var w = 200;
    var q = 255;
    var cir = 240;
    var cir2 = 90;
    var ctx;
    var direction = 1;
    var speed = 10;

    startButton.hide();

    startButton.click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        stopButton.show();
        animation = setInterval(function () {
            animate();
        }, speed);
    });

    stopButton.click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        startButton.show();
        clearInterval(animation)
    });

    increaseButton.click(function () {
        changeSpeed(-10);
    });

    decreaseButton.click(function () {
        changeSpeed(10);
    });

    changeDirection.click(function () {
        direction *= -1;
    })

    function changeSpeed(changeValue) {
        speed += changeValue;
        clearInterval(animation)
        animation = setInterval(function () {
            animate();
        }, speed);
    }

    function animate() {
        x += direction;
        b += direction;
        t += direction;
        w += direction;
        q += direction;
        cir += direction;
        cir2 += direction;

        //update
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
        ctx.fillRect(x, 350, 190, 120);
        ctx.fillRect(b, 410, 60, 60);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(t, 350);
        ctx.lineTo(w, 400);
        ctx.lineTo(q, 400);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#black";
        ctx.fill();

        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cir, 490, 18, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 4;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#black';
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cir2, 490, 18, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 4;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#black';
        ctx.stroke();
    };

    var animation = setInterval(function () {
        animate();
    }, speed);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600">
        <!-- Insert fallback content here -->
    </canvas>
    <div>
        <button id="startAnimation">Start</button>
        <button id="stopAnimation">Stop</button>
        <button id="increase"> Increase the speed</button>
        <button id="decrease"> Decrease the speed</button>
        <button id="changeDirection"> Change direction</button>
    </div>
</body>
```